# How do I fix pip after updating python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I used to use python 3.9, but I recently updated to 3.11 via the python launcher, but pip was looking in the old location where python 3.9 was(I'm using windows). When I entered `pip install <the library I wanted to install>` it gave me an error saying:

> Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe"  "C:\Program Files\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe" install keyboard': The system cannot find the file specified.

I searched on chrome but there was no answer I could use.
How do I fix this error? Thanks!

Comment: Generally if you upgrade Python you would also upgrade `pip`. The error message looks like something on your system is looking in the old location, but there's by far too few details to tell you why. Probably [edit] your question to reveal your OS (clearly Windows) and how exactly you installed and configured the original Python version, and what exactly you did to upgrade it. There are different ways to install Python on Windows, so we'd need to understand which one you used.

Comment: Use `pip --version` to understand where it's coming from, similar to how you use `python --version` and `python -m site`. Use `python -m pip install...` to ensure pip version matches interpreter version. [Tell us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) what you found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. press Win+R
2. run sysdm.cpl
3. go to Advanced tab
4. press Environment Variables
5. In System variables choose variable Path and press Edit button
6. Change old paths to to your new app's paths "C:\Program Files\Python311\python.exe" and "C:\Program Files\Python311\Scripts\pip.exe"
7. reboot